# Embedding of an elliptic curve into $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be a smooth elliptic curve over a field $k$. Let 
$$
i : E \to \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2,
$$
be an embedding. How one can find an explicit canonical forms of equations cutting $E$ in $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2$? Are there analogs of Weierstrass, Hesse and Legendre forms of equations?

Comment: What is the (bi)degree of your embedding?

Comment: $(3,3)$ is not that defined by dimensions of projective spaces?

Comment: For any point $x\in \mathbb P^2$, you can also embed $E$ into $\{x\}\times \mathbb P^2$. This has bidegree $(0,3)$. I don't know whether there are other possibilities.

Comment: Another option is to take an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P} \subset \mathbb{P}^2\times \mathbb{P}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be 3-dimensional spaces. Take a generic element $F \in A^*\otimes B^*\otimes C^*$. Let $F_C$ be the induced map $C \to A^*\otimes B^*$. It gives you a section of the vector bundle $C\otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(A)\times\mathbb{P}(B)}(1,1)$. Its zero locus is an elliptic curve of bidegree $(3,3)$. Analogously it gives you an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}(A)\times \mathbb{P}(C)$ and an elliptic curve in $\mathbb{P}(B)\times\mathbb{P}(C)$. These curves are related to Artin--Shelter algebras.

Vice versa, a generic elliptic curve of bidegree $(3,3)$ can be constructed in this way.

Comment: This is a reformulation of the original question. In fact I asked that question trying to understand better such elliptic tensors i.e. find representatives in each orbit.